# How to add existing folder structure to VS2015 ASP.NET Web Site Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a simple VS2015 solution including an ASP.NET Web App project.

I want to add files from an online example, including their folder structure.

In other VS Project Types, if I click the "Show All Files" menu icon, I can see existing files (not already in the Project) and then "Include in Project".

However, in the ASP.NET Web App project, the "Show All Files" menu icon doesn't show up.

So, how do I either get "Show All Files" to appear for such a project type, or how can I add existing files with their folder structure to an ASP.NET Web App project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there's no "Show All Files" option for an ASP.NET Web App Project.

To see the files I'd added to the file system, that hadn't yet shown up in Visual Studio 2015, all I had to do was:

- Under the Solution, right-click the Project
- click "Refresh Folder"
- The folder that existed in the file system now also showed up in VS2015, as I needed